# Save Variable into LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to save variable into localStorage, the table already saved into localStorage, but the table just display text, i need to save datatable into localStorage for make *datatable view* when page reloaded, but no luck.

the result newTable in localStorage just showing `[object Object]`.

why not `$("#table1").dataTable();` ?

```
 /* Create datatable for new table */
    var newTable = $("#table" + localStorage.Index).dataTable();
    localStorage.setItem("newTable", newTable);
    var save_newTable = localStorage.getItem("newTable");
```

**[My JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4fukuma/gtwnueq8/8/)**

Comment: `localStorage` only stores strings. If you want to store objects you need to convert them to JSON and store that. Read [some documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API).

Comment: don't store an object directly in `localstorage`

Comment: it's possible to save my datatable into localStorage?

Comment: someone can give me reference to save datatable into localStorage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't store an object directly in `localstorage`. In `localstorage`, you can just store strings in key-value form. One thing you can do is convert your object to a JSON string (as nnnnn suggested) and store that.

Then you can read its value from the `localstorage` and parse it back to JSON to use it.

I can't attach a demo as SO prevents us from writing to `localstorage`, but you can see this for reference: [writing table to localstorage](http://jsfiddle.net/cgap4p83/)

Comment: im little bit in javascript, and i dont know what is that *object*, and convert to json.

Comment: Certainly won't be able to stringify OP's object. Is full of functions

Comment: @charlietfl why not ? we can easily convert the table into JSON format, row by row

Comment: Sure...can access the data using the plugin api...but can't stringify that specific object returned by `$('#table').dataTable()`

Comment: @charlietfl oh, yea I get it now

Comment: @CalvinAnanda see my updated answer, it will give you a brief

Comment: I try to learn it.. not yet got a clue, which I see is still [Object object].